# Reading the contents of an externally linked file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Is there a way in JavaScript to get the contents of a linked file without making a second GET request? That is, if I have

```
<link rel="foo" href="bar.txt">
```

the browser should automatically download `bar.txt`. Is there any way to read its contents without getting it again (i.e. via jQuery's `$.get` or similar)?

---

#### Edit

I *could* use a second GET request and as mentioned in the comments there likely wouldn't be a performance hit, but this question is mainly a thought experiment: it seems like it'd be pretty standard functionality, but more and more things point to this not being possible. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Step back for a second and think *if* it matters if it's a `$.get()` request.  Does it?  With the right headers it should be cached already, loaded locally :)

Comment: It likely doesn't matter (although I'm trying to avoid jQuery for this exercise): I'm just curious if linked files are accessible to JavaScript in a similar way that styles are via `document.styleSheets`. That's good to know that `$.get()` uses the cache, though.

Comment: The same holds true for a plain/direct XmlHttpRequest as well, IE especially will cache the hell out of it for you, even if you told it not to :)

Comment: This is a good question! Although my bet is that there is no standardized way to get hold of this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the  tag has absolutly no other purpose than being a placeholder for the source, then the objective is to prevent the first get rather then the second ;) By using another attribute you avoid the default behaviour.

```
<link data-src='file.txt' />
```

'data-...' is a valid HTML5 attribute you can use right now, though the html will not be valid if an older doctype is declared but will still work.

Next when using jQuery:

```
$('link[data-src]').each(function(){
    var self = $(this)
    , src = self.attr('data-src');
    $.get(src, function(fileContent){
        // do stuff with fileContent
    })
});
```

Obviously any element will do rather then the link element when using 'data-...', I use this technique myself to add data in a component based architecture, lazily binding resources and meta information to components without it affecting default behaviours/renditions.

Comment: Interesting approach! I'm interested in seeing if JavaScript can piggy-back off of files that would've already been loaded anyway, though.

Comment: Due to security issues, javascript is not able to read already loaded files, since that would require disc access (tmp internet files) and browsers are generally pretty firm about denying access to files on disc. There's also no API for files loaded inside a page context through means other then XMLHTTPRequests. This is exactly why Ajax has been such a succesful and popular technique, because there are no alternatives ;) Well, you could embed the contents of the file inside the HTML rather then linking to it and quering for it when you need to.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation. Your comment should be part of your answer!